# Keyboard Issue on POP!_OS: HP Laptop 348 G3

Tags: linux, keyboard, pop-os

I am currently using POP!_OS, and my laptop keyboard won't work. I'm having to rely on an external keyboard. I am using an HP 348 G3 laptop and running the latest version of POP!_OS. Additionally, I attempted to boot into another operating system, but the problem continues to persist.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to provide additional information, such as Laptop model, OS version and desktop environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try the solution posited [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033767/keyboard-not-working-after-update-to-18-04/1051720#1051720), or alternatively there is another solution available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard). Note that for the second link, it will likely detect both the external and onboard keyboard in your case (ideally).

As per the first link, visit Settings -> Universal Access -> Typing Assist -> Turn off Slow Keys.

As per the second link, `xinput list` provides a list of connected devices in a tree format.

1. Run `xinput list`
2. Locate the relevant Keyboard name for your system, under `Virtual core keyboard`
3. Note its unique identifier (that is, the `id` associated with the device, formatted as `id=#`)
4. Note its master's `id` (that is, the `id` associated with the master group, formatted as `[slave keyboard (#)]`)
5. Disable the keyboard, using the command `xinput float <id#>`, substituting `<id#>` for the number noted in step 3
6. Finally, reattach the keyboard with the command `xinput reattach <id#> <master#>`, substituting `<id#>` for the number noted in step 3 and `<master#>` for the number in step 4

Please ensure that if you use this method, you detach the `slave keyboard` and not the `master`. That is to say, the id used in `xinput float <id#>` corresponds to the field which contains `id=#`. As stated in the link, `[slave keyboard (#)]` denotes the master id, where `#` is the id.